# An exercise on Fourier Analysis with Dirichlet and Fejer kernels

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let **R(T)** be the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ such that

$f$ is **$2\pi$-periodic** and **integrable over any closed interval of length $2\pi$.**

Let $D_{n}$ be the **Dirichlet kernel** and $K_{n}(f)$ be the **Fejer kernel** meaning that
$D_{n}=\sum_{m=-n}^{n}e_{m}$ , $K_{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}D_m$ and $e_{m}:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ with $e_{m}(t)=e^{imt},\forall t\in\mathbb{R}$

If  $F:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ such that $F=(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|(D_{n}-K_{n})*f|^2}{n})^\frac{1}{2}$ show that $F\in R(T)$ and moreover that $||F||_{2}\leq||f||_{2}$

It's easy to show that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $\phi_{n}:=(D_{n}-K_{n})*f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ with $\phi_{n}=\sum_{m=-n}^{n}\frac{|m|\widehat{f}(m)}{n+1}e_{m}$.

From this we conclude that $(\phi_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of **complex trigonometric polynomials of degree at most n** thus continuous and $2\pi$-periodic.

Therefore if $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ we define $g_{n}:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ with $g_{n}:=\frac{|\phi_{n}|^2}{n}$then the sequence $(g_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of non-negative,continuous and $2\pi$-periodic real functions.From the **monotone convergence theorem** we have that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g_{n}$ is  **Lebesgue integrable** over $\mathbb{R}$ thus **F is also Lebesgue integrable** over $\mathbb{R}$.

**First question**

From continuity of $g_{n}$ and the monotone convergence we cannot conclude that F is also continuous.What about $g_{n}$?They  are not uniformly bounded i think

$||F||_{2}^{2}:=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|F(t)|^2dt$

$=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}g_{n}(t)dt=lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{N}g_{n}(t)dt$

$=lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{|\phi_{n}(t)|^{2}}{n}dt=lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|\phi_{n}(t)|^{2}dt$

$=lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|\sum_{m=-n}^{n}\frac{|m|\widehat{f}(m)}{n+1}e^{imt}|^{2}dt$

$=lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}||\sum_{m=-n}^{n}\frac{|m|\widehat{f}(m)}{n+1}e_{m}||_{2}^{2}$

**orthogonality**

$=lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=-n}^{n}||\frac{|m|\widehat{f}(m)}{n+1}e_{m}||_{2}^{2}$

$=lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=-n}^{n}\frac{m^{2}|\widehat{f}(m)|^{2}}{(n+1)^{2}}||e_{m}||_{2}^{2}$

$=lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=-n}^{n}\frac{m^{2}|\widehat{f}(m)|^{2}}{(n+1)^{2}}$

**Second question**

I have tried to write the double sum differently as follows

$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\{[\sum_{n-1\leq|m|\leq n}{m^{2}|\widehat{f}(m)|^{2}}][\sum_{ν=n}^{N}\frac{1}{ν
(ν+1)^{2}}]\}$

$\leq\sum_{n=1}^{N}\{[\sum_{n-1\leq|m|\leq n}{n^{2}|\widehat{f}(m)|^{2}}][\sum_{ν=n}^{N}\frac{1}{ν
(ν+1)^{2}}]\}$

$=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\{[\sum_{n-1\leq|m|\leq n}{|\widehat{f}(m)|^{2}}][\sum_{ν=n}^{N}\frac{n^{2}}{ν(ν+1)^{2}}]\}$

If i could conclude that $\sum_{ν=n}^{N}\frac{n^{2}}{ν(ν+1)^{2}}\leq 1$ then it would follow that

$||F||_{2}\leq||f||_{2}$

**Using the integral test for series convergence and the upper estimates for partial sums of the form**

$\sum_{v=n}^{N}h(v)\leq h(n)+\int_{n}^{N}h(t)dt\leq h(n)+\int_{n}^{\infty}h(t)dt$ where $h(t)=\frac{v^2}{t(t+1)^2}\forall t\in[1,\infty )$

we get that $\sum_{ν=n}^{N}\frac{n^{2}}{ν(ν+1)^{2}}\leq 1$